# NSURLConnection retrieving JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsurlconnection

I am using PromiseKit and I want to retrieve a JSON file.

```
[NSURLConnection GET:@"http://127.0.0.1/pack01.json"].then(^(NSDictionary *json) {
    NSArray *questions = json[@"questions"];
```

Everything is fine on localhost but when I try it from another source (same file) it gives me an error:

```
[NSURLConnection GET:@"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11377305/resources/pack01.json"].then(^(NSDictionary *json) {
    NSArray *questions = json[@"questions"];
```

**Error**

*[__NSCFData objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb07c880*

**JSON file:**

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11377305/resources/pack01.json

Why is it working on localhost?
I would appreciate any suggestions or even any thoughts on what questions I should be asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that you're being passed an `NSData`  rather than an `NSDictionary` from the remote URL.

The PromiseKit documentation states:

> PromiseKit reads the response headers and decodes the result you actually wanted (in a background thread):

Therefore it's a safe bet that your remote server (which is DropBox in this case) isn't indicating that the returned data is formatted as JSON. So PromiseKit isn't parsing it.

EDIT: confirmed. DropBox is returning:

```
Content-Type    text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

So PromiseKit has no way of knowing that the included data is meant to be JSON. You need a server that will return an `application/json` `Content-Type`. Or else you can force the JSON parse yourself, but then you're missing out on a large part of the PromiseKit benefit as you end up writing the same boilerplate code as the rest of us.

Comment: I think that's the problem. How do you check the Content-Type?

Comment: I used the Safari web inspector. Enable 'Show Develop menu in menu bar' in the 'Advanced' application settings, go to any web page and select 'Develop -> Show Web Inspector', then open your JSON URL in that same tab, select pack01.json from the list on the left pane, press the 'Resource' button in the top right and check out the 'Response Header's in the newly revealed right pane.